# Why is it trying to access the database on the main thread?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-jetpack-compose

I am getting this error while trying to display Room data in a LazyColumn in my project.

Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time

I don't know why it is trying to access the database since I'm getting it with a ViewModelScope. Bellow is my MainActivity code and the ViewModel

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val viewModel: UserViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {

            val users = viewModel.userList.value

LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
                            items(users){data->
                                MyCard(data)
                            }
```

```
@HiltViewModel
class UserViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: MainRepository
) : ViewModel() {
val userList: MutableState<List<User>> = mutableStateOf(listOf())

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                val result: List<User> = repository.getAllUsers()
                userList.value = result
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.e("SSS", "${e.message.toString()}; ${e.stackTrace}")
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It wasn't, that was it. Thanks

Comment: Ooops, I deleted my comment to flesh out the explanation as an answer. Make sure both the repository function *and* the DAO function that it calls are marked `suspend`. If you only change the repository function, it makes the warning go away but it will still be blocking.

Answer (score 1):

> When launch { ... } is used without parameters, it inherits the
> context (and thus dispatcher) from the CoroutineScope it is being
> launched from.

Use IO thread to execute your code

```
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
      try {
        val result: List<User> = repository.getAllUsers()
        userList.postValue(result)
      } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e("SSS", "${e.message.toString()}; ${e.stackTrace}")
      }
    }
```

Comment: Now you are updating the LiveData from a background thread, so it will crash for that reason. You should let `launch` run on the main thread normally and wrap `getAllUsers()` in a `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)`, or better yet, simply mark it as a suspend function in the DAO and repository so Room will take care of the backgrounding for you.

Comment: According to the designers of coroutines, it is atypical to override the default dispatcher of a CoroutineScope, and `withContext` is preferred. Since the UI is the only framework thing that demands a specific thread, and many methods require it, it makes sense for it to be the default that you work in, and that's why `viewModelScope`'s context already uses it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are following the pattern of your repository passing through functions from the DAO, you should mark this function in your DAO as a `suspend` function. This will cause it to automatically use a background thread. Then mark your corresponding repository function `suspend` so it can call the other suspend function.

Then in your coroutine, since `getAllUsers()` is a proper suspend function that internally handles proper use of background threads, there is nothing more you need to change.

The reason it gives you the warning is that by default, the `viewModelScope` runs on the main thread. It is up to you to wrap blocking calls in `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` to run them in a background thread. But if you use `suspend` functions from the DAO, you don't have to worry about that because the function isn't blocking.